# Why does this entity framework query fail when there are null database fields?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I'm working with MVC3 C#.NET.  I have a query that (up to now worked) which returns rows based off of the companyID:

```
var records = db.groupsToClassesMapping.Where(r => r.CompanyID == CompanyId);
```

The model looks like this:

```
[Table("Rpt_GroupsToClasses")]
public class GroupToClass
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    public string ClassName { get; set; }
    public int ClassIndex { get; set; }
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
}
```

and the DBContext looks like this:

```
    public DbSet<GroupToClass> GroupsToClassesMapping { get; set; }
```

It used to be all of the table entries were filled, and the query would return results:

```
ID | Group Name | ClassName | ClassIndex | CompanyID
-----------------------------------------------------
1  | Pine       | Merch     | 1          | 1
2  | Oak        | Non-merch | 4          | 1
```

However, I find myself needing to have some of the entries blank:

```
ID | Group Name | ClassName | ClassIndex | CompanyID
-----------------------------------------------------
1  | Pine       | Merch     | 1          | 1
2  | Oak        | NULL      | NULL       | 1
```

and my query (where(r => r.companyID == CompanyId)) doesn't return anything.  Is there something I need to do to the model fields to make this work right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make ClassIndex nullable by changing the datatype to `int?`.

Comment: Ding ding ding.  Thank you.  I will accept this in exactly 9 minutes when SO deigns to let me.